# Weird empty set result on MYSQL query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query to find all PMA tasks linked to a non current pma. We follow single table inheritance for our different task types (entity_task table). All current pma ids are stored in the employee table.

My first attempt was as follows :

```
SELECT * FROM entity_task 
WHERE dtype = 'PMATask'
AND pma_id NOT IN (SELECT pma_id FROM employee);
```

I expected this to return all tasks linked to a non current PMA but it just returns an empty set.

The entity task table structure is as folows

```
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+--------------------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type        | Null | Key | Default            | Extra          |
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+--------------------+----------------+
| id                        | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL               | auto_increment |
| date_created              | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL               |                |
| version                   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL               |                |
| employee_course_id        | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL               |                |
| task_id                   | bigint(20)  | NO   | MUL | NULL               |                |
| tenant_id                 | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL               |                |
| date_updated              | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL               |                |
| dtype                     | varchar(31) | NO   |     | EmployeeCourseTask |                |
| meeting_id                | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL               |                |
| pma_id                    | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL               |                |
| critical_talent_review_id | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL               |                |
| working_week_id           | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL               |                |
| leave_form_id             | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL               |                |
| leave_adjustment_id       | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL               |                |
| remuneration_run_id       | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL               |                |
+---------------------------+-------------+------+-----+--------------------+----------------+
```

We finally managed to get all tasks linked to non current PMA's by using the following query

```
SELECT et.id 
FROM entity_task et 
LEFT JOIN employee e ON et.pma_id = e.pma_id 
WHERE e.pma_id IS NULL 
AND et.dtype = 'PMATask';
```

I really feel like I am missing something here, any advice ??

Comment: Can you show sample data with expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Your 2 queries are not equivalent,the first one checks **all** pma_id in entity_task which dont exists in employee.

The second one checks the same thing with the addition of the JOIN condition,all pma_id in entity_task which dont exists in employee but only for each subset of et.pma_id = e.pma_id.

Here is a rewrite of the first query to take this into account

```
SELECT * FROM entity_task 
WHERE dtype = 'PMATask'
AND pma_id NOT EXISTS(SELECT pma_id FROM employee WHERE employee.pma_id=entity_task.pma_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Non Current pma_id will be null in Employee table, so you may need to include that condition in your first query

```
SELECT * FROM entity_task 
WHERE dtype = 'PMATask'
AND pma_id NOT IN (SELECT pma_id FROM employee where pma_id is NULL);
```

Hope, it gives intended data.

Comment: Hi @Mihai , unfortunately it still returns an empty set even with the null check